# Нужно правильно написать regEx на Url

Tags: javascript

Нужно что-бы в консоле вывело true

```js
const partUrl = 'westus2.dev.genazure.com'
const regExUrl = new RegExp(`**-${partUrl}/sign_in`); //need to change
   
const url = 'https://web.api01-westus2.dev.genazure.com/sign_in'
console.log(regExUrl.test(url)) //expected result true
```

Comment: А что нужно - должны догадаться?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нужно правильно написать regEx. Исправить regExUrl что-бы тест прошел

Comment: Отлично. Ещё бы знать что тут неправильно и в чём заключается задача.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Неправильно написан regExUrl

Comment: С чего ты взял что неправильно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Потому что не работает

Comment: Что именно не работает? Задача какая? Может секрет раскроешь?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нажмите кнопку выполнить код, там будет ошибка

Comment: Я не спрашивал какая ошибка. Я спросил другое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю необходимо проверить содержится ли часть доменного имени в ссылке через регулярные выражения, вот мой ответ:

```js
const partUrl = 'westus2.dev.genazure.com';
const regExUrl = new RegExp(`^https?:\/\/[a-z0-9.]+-${partUrl}\/sign_in$`);
   
const url = 'https://web.api01-westus2.dev.genazure.com/sign_in';
console.log(regExUrl.test(url));
```

Comment: Зачем тут регулярка, если можно includes у строки применить?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в заголовке вопроса указано, что необходимо составить regEx на URL.

Comment: Да там может быть и "хочу забивать ладонью гвозди в бетон" %)) Просто надо понимать, что иногда автор хочет какую-то дичь)

Answer (score -1):

Раз так упорно не хотите отвечать на вопрос, что именно требуется в задаче, то вот вам такой ответ:

```js
const partUrl = 'westus2.dev.genazure.com'
const regExUrl = new RegExp(`.*`);
   
const url = 'https://web.api01-westus2.dev.genazure.com/sign_in'
console.log(regExUrl.test(url))
```

Нет ошибки - нет проблем